# How to align ProcessingJS sketches in HTML

Tags: html, canvas, alignment, processing, processing.js

I'm a beginner in Processing.js and HTML, and I want to align my sketch to the sides of page. How can I align this `ex.pde` sketch placed in `canvas` to the left, right or center ?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <title>EXAMPLE</title>
    <script>src="processing-1.4.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 align="center">Sine Wave to Infinity</h1>
    <canvas  data-processing-sources="ex.pde"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if we're using proper HTML5, we need to change this code a little.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
    <title>example</title>
    <script src="processing-1.4.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sine Wave to Infinity</h1>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="ex.pde"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

(added a meta tag, link is not closing, there was a rogue bracket in the script tag, and you had an obsolete styling attribute in the h1).

Now the h1 and canvas are flush on the left. aligning them on center means you want to set the "text-align" property for the parent of both h1 and canvas to "center", so in this case

```
body { text-align: center; }
```

to align right, same trick, but text-align: right, instead. However, for placement purposes it'll be better to wrap the h1 and canvas element in a div, align them inside that div (assign text-align to that div rather than body) and then you can place that div wherever you want while keeping the h1 and canvas aligned.